# Rebuild Realm Database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a swift project with Realm installed via cocoapods. I accidentally deleted the realm database via `rm path/to/realm/database` in my terminal. Whenever I run the app I receive the error below:

```
'RLMException', reason: 'open() failed: No such file or directory'
```

My questions is, how do I rebuild the realm database?

Comment: Jason, do you mean you deleted the Realm file?

Comment: Correct. Your answer worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened to me too, a while back! Basically, just reset your your IOS Simulator that you are testing on.

Click on "IOS Simulator" menu, then "Reset Contents And Settings"

Let me know if this works...